# Ttk label not displaying TextVar

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a GUI with Tkinter (Tcl/Tk version 8.6.12) on Python 3.9. Up until now, I mostly had experience with pure Tk, but wanted to try Ttk out. My problem is that running:

```py
someText = tk.StringVar(value="Some Text")
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=someText).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))
```

does reserve some space for the string, but doesn't display it. When using the `tk.Label` class, it works like a charm...

What am I doing wrong, or is the `ttk.Label` class broken?

EDIT: here is my full MNWE (I wrapped everything in a function because I will need to integrate everything with some other code I have already written and this is the best way I've found to do it):

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def generateGUI():
    # Generates the main window
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Some interesting title")
    root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

    # Adds a frame for themed tk
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # setup the frame to scale with the window horizontally
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # setup the frame to scale with the window vertically

    # Creates a canvas
    canv = Canvas(mainframe, bg="green")
    canv.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, E, S, W))

    # Sets some information panel up
    info = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
    info.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, E))
    title = StringVar(value="<title>")
    text1 = StringVar(value="<text1>")
    text2 = StringVar(value="<text2>")
    text3 = StringVar(value="<text3>")
    # Adds the different labels
    ttk.Label(info, font=25, textvariable=title).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N, columnspan=2)
    ttk.Label(info, text="Info 1: ").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(info, text="Info 2: ").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(info, text="Info 3: ").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(info, textvariable=text1).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
    ttk.Label(info, textvariable=text2).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
    ttk.Label(info, textvariable=text3).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E)


    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
        child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    return root

gui = generateGUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works fine for me.  Did you change the foreground color of `ttk.Label` using `ttk.Style` somewhere else?

Comment: @acw1668 no I didn't...

Comment: Then it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 there we go

Comment: It is because those `StringVar`s are local variables inside the function which are garbage collected after the function returns.  If you replace `return root` by `root.mainloop()`, then those labels can be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance of `StringVar` is a local variable. Make it/them an instance variable if you're using classes, or a global variable if not.

```
def generateGUI():
    global title
    ...
    title = StringVar(value="<title>")
    ttk.Label(info, font=25, textvariable=title)
```

Comment: OP is not using class, so instance variable cannot be used.

Comment: @acw1668: good grief, how did I miss that! Thanks for letting me know. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it works, but it does indeed...
EDIT: nevermind, didn't see @acw1668's comment under the original post...

Answer (score -1):

This example code is working. You need to `import ttk`  and change remove `sticky`.
[why_no_sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882497/ttk-gridsticky-ew-with-grid-columnconfigure-doesnt-work-properly-for-no) - good example on the link how grid works.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

mainframe = tk.Tk()

someText = tk.StringVar(value="Some Text")
label1 = ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=someText)
label1.grid(column=0, row=0)

mainframe.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not encouraged to use `.grid` on the label assignment. Better split it up with a variable.

Comment: That would somewhat break my alignment, but I will try it out with pack instead of grid. Thanks for the help

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, same problem persists...

Comment: This is not a solution to the question that was asked.

Comment: @BryanOakley when code was first posted it was a solution to the question.

Comment: Did you actually try your solution? The use of sticky `absolutely` has no bearing on the problem.